# Evaluate None object in boost python

Tags: python, boost, boost-python

I am passing a list of (mostly) floats to a module in boost python, some elements are None objects. In the C++ code I am extracting the floats like so:

```
for(i=0;i<boost::python::len(list) - window_len + 1;i++) {
  double value = boost::python::extract<double>(list[i]);
}
```

This is obviously problematic when list[i] points to a python None object. As such I wrote something like this:

```
for(i=0;i<boost::python::len(list) - window_len + 1;i++) {
  if(list[i] == NULL) continue;
  double value = boost::python::extract<double>(list[i]);
}
```

and

```
for(i=0;i<boost::python::len(list) - window_len + 1;i++) {
  if(list[i] == boost::python::api::object()) continue;
  double value = boost::python::extract<double>(list[i]);
}
```

because apparently boost::python::api::object() evaluates to None. However, neither of these work. How can I check that list[i] in a python None object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your last approach, comparing against `boost::python::api::object()` should work. However, it only checks if the element it actually `None`. The extraction can still fail if the value is neither `None` nor a numeric type (a string for example).

You should use `check()` to ensure that the conversion was successful (if it fails, the module will throw an exception if you use the value anyway):

```
for( size_t i=0, len=boost::python::len(list); i<len; ++i ) {
    boost::python::extract<double> value(list[i]);
    if( !value.check() ) continue; // check if the conversion was successful
    double d = value; // now you can use value as double
}
```

Comment: This compiled just fine but when I ran it in python I still got "No registered converter was able to produce a C++ rvalue of type double from this Python object of type NoneType". Supposedly it is still having trouble with "boost::python::extract<double> value(list[i]);"?

Comment: @NCAggie could you provide a [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/) (both C++ and python) that demonstrates the error? Also what version of boost and python are you using?

Comment: Ok, This works in my simple example. It must be something else in the code. I'm on the hunt... Thanks Anon